# Sed replacing every line rather than one line

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I'm trying to replace a specific line number in a test file with a string made up from variables. My issue being it seems to replace every line in the file with the string, rather than just the specific line.

It needs to be line number, as the content will often change, it's somewhat of a status file and if anyone has any better ideas on how to achieve this, i'm all ears.

In essence, as sync jobs complete they should record the start and completion time of the sync for each job in the status.config file, and each time the sync runs for that specific job, it should overwrite the current line.

```
laststartline=$(grep -n '$RCLONESESSION'LastStart $scriptdirectory/$mountsconfig | awk -F: '{print $1}') ##OBTAIN LINE NUMBER FOR LAST START TIME FOR THIS SESSION


sed -i ''$laststartline's/.*/'$RCLONESESSION'LastStart:'$time'/' $scriptdirectory/$mountsconfig ##REPLACE LINE IN MOUNTS.CONFIG WITH RELEVANT TIMESTAMP FOR JOB START
```

Can anyone see why the entire file get's overwritten with the content, rather than just the line specified in $laststartline

If it helps:

```
$RCLONESESSION is predefined as rclone2
$time is defined as the current date and time in MM-DD-YYYY-HH-MM-SS format.
$scriptdirectory is defined as /root/scripts/
$mountsconfig is defined as status.config
```

Line 22 is the line I'm trying to replace, which is `rclone2LastStart:?` and should be replaced with `rclone2LastStart:MM-DD-YYYY-HH-MM-SS` from the `$time` variable.

This needs to be a different line, depending on the lookup as `$RCLONESESSION` could be a different session, and this need to replace a different file in `$mountsconfig`.

I'm hoping it's something obvious in my `sed` command, as if I run this directly from terminal, and not within my script, it replaces the one line as expected.

If it's run within the script, it replaces EVERY line with the `$time` parameter.

Comment: Is `$RCLONESESSION` supposed to be a literal string, or a variable to be expanded? you appear to be treating it as the former in your `grep` expression but as the latter in the `sed` replacement. Run with `set -x` and check that `$laststartline` isn't empty.

Comment: $laststartline is not empty, it correctly comes back with the line number.

Comment: $RCLONESESSION is supposed to literal for that one run of the scirpt, it's declared dependent on the name of the file, after some trimming, so in this occasion it is equal to rclone2

Comment: it makes it less confusing if you use something like `$literalStringThatBeginsWithDollarSign`

Comment: Why are you weaving in and out of quotes? In any case your shell variables are unquoted. Best is to put all under double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a fool now, it's the quotes causing the issue in $RCLONESESSION, on the $laststartline variable.

```
laststartline=$(grep -n '$RCLONESESSION'LastStart $scriptdirectory/$mountsconfig | awk -F: '{print $1}') ##OBTAIN LINE NUMBER FOR LAST START TIME FOR THIS SESSION
```

Needed changing to:

```
laststartline=$(grep -n "$RCLONESESSION"LastStart $scriptdirectory/$mountsconfig | awk -F: '{print $1}') ##OBTAIN LINE NUMBER FOR LAST START TIME FOR THIS SESSION
```

All works now, thanks for the help @steeldriver.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to a different question. There is no need for the grep to find the line number, as sed can search for the line itself.

```
sed -i '/'$RCLONESESSION'LastStart:/s/.*/'$RCLONESESSION'LastStart:'$time'/' $scriptdirectory/$mountsconfig
```

in other words instead of using a line number, use the expression `/text/` to say what line to apply it to. It could probably be made even shorter by just applying the match to every line and being more selective about the edit.

```
sed -i 's/\('$RCLONESESSION'LastStart:\).*/\1'$time'/' $scriptdirectory/$mountsconfig
```

(If the $RCLONESESSION is not at the start of the line then change `s/\(` to `s/^.*\(`)